# vb.net running a loop that checks if lmb is down, and breaks an enclosed loop is up

Tags: vb.net

I've been trying to do what the title says for a few hours so far. I'm attempting to make a loop that is triggered by a button that checks if lmb is down for more than 100ms and runs a secondary loop. If lmb is up, the second loop should break, but not the first. And then after all that, when a button is pressed, the first loop should be broken.

Sorry for the horrible explanation, my brain is pretty fried over what should be a pretty simple task.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please take your time and **read** [How to ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to get a better insight on how to post a new question around here and get a good answer.

Comment: What is `lmb` in this context?

Comment: leftmousebutton

Answer (score 0):

Don't think in terms of loops. Think in terms of Timers. Use a timer instance that checks your conditions every 50ms or so.

Comment: The timer idea is great and helps out *just a bit* with the spaghetti. The other issue that I haven't had too much time to mess with is how to detect if lmb is down or up.

Comment: There's an event for that.

Comment: That doesn't work, I did however try this library (https://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/) and it works for mouse down, but there is no option for mouse up.